# Replacing multiple strings in a .oft Outlook email template not working as expected

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-5.0

I'm trying to replace multiple values within an Outlook Email Template file (.oft).

I did have this working at some point between commits, not entirely sure what's causing my issues.

As I understand HTMLBody is required to retain formatting.

The issue is that only the last two instances of .Replace are functioning

```
void BtnGenerateClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Outlook.Application emailApp = new Outlook.Application();
    Outlook.MailItem createTemplate = emailApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\Documents\\OFTFiles\\test-template.oft") as Outlook.MailItem;
    createTemplate.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
    createTemplate.Subject = "Test Email sent " + '\u0040' + " " + tbTime.Text + " on " + currentDate;
            
    /* START Replace Text from Numeric Up Down Value Property  */
    var changed0 = createTemplate.HTMLBody.Replace("{0}",nud0.Value.ToString());
    createTemplate.HTMLBody = changed0;
            
    var changed1 = createTemplate.HTMLBody.Replace("{1}",nud1.Value.ToString());
    createTemplate.HTMLBody = changed1;
            
    var changed2 = createTemplate.HTMLBody.Replace("{2}",nud2.Value.ToString());
    createTemplate.HTMLBody = changed2;
            
    var changed3 = createTemplate.HTMLBody.Replace("{3}",nud3.Value.ToString());
    createTemplate.HTMLBody = changed3;
            
    var changed4 = createTemplate.HTMLBody.Replace("{4}",nud4.Value.ToString());
    createTemplate.HTMLBody = changed4;
            
    var changed5 = createTemplate.HTMLBody.Replace("{5}",nud5.Value.ToString());
    createTemplate.HTMLBody = changed5;
            
    var changed6 = createTemplate.HTMLBody.Replace("{6}",nud6.Value.ToString());
    createTemplate.HTMLBody = changed6;
    /* END Replace Text from Numeric Up Down Value Property */

    /* START Replace Text from Textbox Text Property */
    var changed7 = createTemplate.HTMLBody.Replace("{7}",tb7.Text);
    createTemplate.HTMLBody = changed7;
            
    var changed8 = createTemplate.HTMLBody.Replace("{8}",tb8.Text);
    createTemplate.HTMLBody = changed8;
            
    var changed9 = createTemplate.HTMLBody.Replace("{9}",tb9.Text);
    createTemplate.HTMLBody = changed9;
            
    var changed10 = createTemplate.HTMLBody.Replace("{10}",tb10.Text);
    createTemplate.HTMLBody = changed10;
            
    var changed11 = createTemplate.HTMLBody.Replace("{11}",tb11.Text);
    createTemplate.HTMLBody = changed11;
    /* END Replace Text from Textbox Text Property */
            
    createTemplate.Display(createTemplate);
            
}
```

**Numeric Up Downs**
nud0 to nud5 are default numericUpDowns with a max of 9999. nud6 has been modified to have 1 decimal place and has a max of 100.

**Textboxes**
tb7 to tb11 are all default, limited to 15 characters. Characters used include A-Z and 0-9.

**.OFT Template Example**
[image: Template Body]

Comment: Provide the template body, your dropdown values and textfield values into the question.

Comment: Edited to add these. Very basic at the moment (proof of concept).

Comment: Can you please also add `createTemplate.HTMLBody` as a snippet to the question.

Comment: There is no snippet. HTMLBody is a property of the MailItem interface within Microsoft.Office.InterOp.Outlook

Comment: See: [_MailItem.HTMLBody Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.htmlbody?view=outlook-pia)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reproduced the part of your project.

But it is working.

My project and .oft file are uploaded at [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1l47Mlz-SihkWK3WRppH7znO_plNeM_8B?usp=sharing).

You can run and test.

Check my solution if you've done any silly mistakes at yours.

If still doesn't work then...

**Ultimate Solution:**

Possibly it is because of Visual Studio's stupid caching or another issue.

**Resolve attempt:**

1. Try **cleaning** your solution and then **rebuild**.
2. If doesn't work, then **close** all instances of Visual Studio and
   then **start** again.
3. If still it doesn't work, then restart your PC.

Answer (score 0):

The [Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-5.0) function returns a new string in which all occurrences of a specified string in the current instance are replaced with another specified string, using the provided comparison type which is not specified. I'd suggest checking the actual values used for the `Replace` function and use the comparison type which specifies the culture, case, and sort rules to be used by certain overloads of the `Compare(String, String)` and `Equals(Object)` methods.

Another aspect is that you don't get a well-formatted HTML string returned from the `Replace` function. So, therefore it fails to update the message body. What value do you want set instead of placeholders?

Answer (score 0):

Since your place holder look like [`string.Format`'s zero-based indexed placeholders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format#the-format-method-in-brief), you can just use [`string.Format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format). You'll get better performance out of it.